# Activity not responding error on emulator when using webservices in json parsing?

Tags: android-emulator

Am new to android, am developing application with websevices using json parsing  with httpget method,cant use http post method in android actually.

It working fine normally, but many time it shows the error on emulator like activity not responding force close activity.when i put that url in browser it shows the result .but i don't know why this activity not responding error came.

I think the httprequest took more time to retrieve the data from server,but am not sure. any one help me to how to avoid this error or how to minimize this .

I want know what are the possibilities to get this activity not responding error.

Thanks,

Lakshmanan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform blocking operations such as I/O in a separate thread - see the below linked resource:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html:

> In Android, the system guards against applications that are insufficiently responsive for a period of time by displaying a dialog to the user, called the Application Not Responding (ANR) dialog, shown at right in Figure 1. The user can choose to let the application continue, but the user won't appreciate having to act on this dialog every time he or she uses your application. It's critical to design responsiveness into your application, so that the system never has cause to display an ANR dialog to the user.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid ANR (Application Not Responding) dialog,

Your business logic code is inside doBackground() of AsyncTask and You may also need to override onPostExecute(),etc. After that it is better to invoke the async task in a Service (bound or normal service).

Service:
(bound service or normal service based on your requirement)

From, android office documentation:
A service is "bound" when an application component binds to it by calling bindService(). A bound service offers a client-server interface that allows components to interact with the service, send requests, get results, and even do so across processes with interprocess communication (IPC). A bound service runs only as long as another application component is bound to it. Multiple components can bind to the service at once, but when all of them unbind, the service is destroyed.